# Where exactly to place the code to retrieve products by category

Tags: magento-1.9, module

this is what I came to:

1. First I needed to go to a folder called Local
2. Then I had to create my own namespace which I called
   NamespaceTesting
3. Then I created the name of my module MymoduleTesting
4. Then I had to create several folders inside MyModuleTesting like controllers, models, blocks, and etc
5. Inside etc, I had to add a config.xml file
6. Inside controllers, I added a controller.php file
7. Also, inform Magento of the existence of my module at
   app/modules/MyModuleTexting.xml

and yes, I read that I had to clear the cache so that Magento finally gets notice of that new module but, please, I don't want to mess with the cache as this is a production site that sells a lot and I would go into panic mode if I crashed the application.

Since all I want  is to extract some data like, give me all products with their price, their description, short description belonging to a specific category, I would prefer to be able to just paste the code somewhere so that I can export it as I need that data for another database not based on Magento.

Could anyone kindly tell me where I can do that without any risk of crashing the app? Be detailed please, as I have been a few hours with Magento and I have already learned a bit.

Thank you for the editing I could not get it properly formatted>

UPDATE INFO

I know about the Magento options to export Products and Customers, but that is maybe too much. Ideally, I d like to be able to obtain the data already specific

Just visualize the category tree like

```
Homeopathy
OTC
Trademarks
  - A
  - B
```

how do I get all products from category B?

I have seen the code to collect that data, I just am not sure where to actually paste it safely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to System > Import/Export > Export and then choose products from Entity Type and csv from Export File Format. This will save all products into something that can be opened by a spreadsheet application like MS Excel.

Comment: ps don't worry about clearing the cache, you won't break the website :)

Comment: ps again - if you try and keep your questions brief and factual you'll find that you're more likely to get responses from people who know a lot more than I do

Comment: I know but if I just ask a question without any code they will thumb me down for not having tried, so I wanted to prove that I indeed have done a lot of reading and exploring around but not so much as to try things I am not sure about,.